# Hyperledger fabric "make peer"command fails

Tags: makefile, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I try to set up hyperledger fabric-0.6 in windows 10 following the guide [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md). (deploying environment in vagrant)
Finishing all prerequisites, I ssh into vagrant and after executing the command

```
make peer
```

It responds as:

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 729504 729509
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Fetched 3769 kB in 18s (207 kB/s)
update-java-alternatives: directory does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
The command '/bin/sh -c core/chaincode/shim/java/javabuild.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'build/image/javaenv/.dummy' failed
make: *** [build/image/javaenv/.dummy] Error 1
```

I wanna know what's going wrong here (Is it about Makefile?)and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have java installed in your image.

`apt-get install default-jdk-headless`